# How to prevent funny characters on Home Page

Tags: child-theme, characters, theme-twenty-fifteen

*This is a challenge for the sharpest and most experienced WordPress specialists*

I am building a site in the WP Twenty Fifteen theme.

I created a bare-bones minimum home page at http://bit.ly/1zlmpKS

The first time you hit the page, it looks fine. When you refresh the browser you get a series of funny characters:

[image]

How can I fix this?

**Amendment:**
Not sure how or if this relates and does what it does, but when I am logged into WordPress (as Super Admin) the home page never displays the funky characters. I can refresh and refresh and refresh dozens of times and it displays fine everytime. But the minute I logout of WP the home page shows the funny characters. I have an inner page on the new site as well, and it renders fine, consistently and all the time.

**Background & History:**
I started out installing the Quark theme. Then I created my own "starter" child theme for the site. I could never get the child theme to take until, say hours later, all of a sudden my child theme started working. So I continued trying to tweak the child theme just to see if I could use it as a building block for my new site. Admittedly, this is my first crack at using the Quark starter theme and my first attempt to learn and utilize a child theme. Well after days of frustration, I thought maybe the W3 Total Cache plugin was the issue. So I network-deactivated it. Still no luck. Then I pulled out the child theme and the Quark theme and simply went with the WP out-of-the box Twenty Fifteen theme. That's when the funny characters surfaced. So I believe somehow and someway the W3 Total Cache plugin is messing with this network and the network site. I have dozens of other sites on my Multisite network install and none of them are misbehaving. W3 Total Cache is a standard plugin I activate for each new network I setup on my server. I have a shortlist of standard plugins I use across all networks and W3 Total Cache is one of them. Oh well...I am at a total loss.

**Something else that's peculiar:**
When you hit the home page - it's fine. When you refresh the home page it renders the funny characters. But then if you wait for 5-10 mins and hit the home page again it renders fine. What might that mean in the WordPress world?

**Next Trial & Error Test:**
I just re-installed Quark theme and network activated my Child Theme. The theme works -- so it is not a theme issue. The funny characters still appear on the home page on refresh under the Quark Child Theme. So it is some sort of unexplained caching issue, I think.

Comment: I'm out of my depth, but that you only receive these characters on subsequent loads makes me suspect some sort of cache failure. Do you have any plugins installed/have you tried disabling all plugins? I would also try disabling any caching features provided by your webserver.

Comment: I think boscho might be right. There are known issues tied to caching plugins causing garbled encoding problems. It's for sure a strange problem. If your not able to get it fixed, a fresh install may be the way to go. If you do decide to do a fresh install, make sure to delete the old install rather then just installing over it.

Comment: Not sure if it will help at all, but I inspected your http response headers for both cases and they are different. Maybe it will point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you @boscho. I suspected it was cache too so I network deactivated the W3 Total Cache plugin which has never done anything for my sites but cause problems. Now I think the plugin is deactivated but I can't be 100% sure. how does one go about totally and completely deactivating the plugin on a network site?

Comment: Thanks @oneThingSimple. I can't do a fresh install because this site is a new network site added on to my WP Multisite system with dozens of sites in it already. BTW all the other sites run just fine and a number of them have the W3 Total Cache plugin activated.

Comment: see my amendment to my OQ.

Comment: @tammy I'm not sure. I wonder if there is an issue with any of the options for this one blog in particular. I certainly don't have a good answer. Have you tried any other themes just to try to isolate the issue? Maybe deactivating this theme from SuperAdmin console for this site, possibly deleting + reinstalling or just reactivating the theme? (for the plugin question, if you rename the folder the plugin is in it won't run, but that's not the same as deactivating it, if it's showing that it's not activated then you should be ok I believe) Good luck to you though, I hope you do find a solution.

Comment: Thanks @oneThingSimple. I added some background and history to my OQ.

Comment: this doesn't seem like it's anything theme-related, the issue is on a deeper level. the difference between a successful page load and and unsuccessful is that the former has a `Transfer-Encoding:chunked` header while the latter has `Content-Length:440` header. are you certain all cache plugin remnants have been purged? your .htaccess file is 100% clean of all W3TC rules?

Comment: Thanks for helping @Milo. (1) I think all cache remnants are gone but I am not familiar enough to know how to confirm that. `W3 Total Cache` plugin has been network deactivated for this site. (2) this is the only directive in my wp-config.php script file -- `define('WP_CACHE', true); // Added by W3 Total Cache`. I am running WP Multisite with dozens of other sites that work fine and have the W3 Total Cache plugin activated. Should I just scrap W3TC all together? I have no problem doing so.<more...>

Comment: <concluded> I merely added it because it in the top 10 plugin must haves on all the sites that talk about how best to setup WP.

Comment: If W3TC is deactivated, you should remove `define('WP_CACHE', true);`. Have you verified that .htaccess files are clean of any rules added by W3TC? You don't have to scrap the plugin entirely, it's just important to be 100% certain it's not the cause of the problem so you can move on to looking elsewhere.

Comment: Ok. Thanks @Milo. I will pick back up on this tomorrow morning - in about 17 hours from now. I'll post back then and @ you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it thanks to [at]OnethingSimple and @milo.

It was the `W3 Total Cache` plugin. I removed it from my server and everything works fine.

Here's the path I had to take.

Step 1 - went into my network admin on the site having the problem to confirm that `W3TC` was not activate or network active -- and it was not.

Step 2 - walked through each of my other networks (over a dozen) to **Network Deactivate** the `W3TC plugin` -- again it is one of the standard plugins I install on every new network.

*Here's was an interesting finding:*
[image]

Each network site showed this error screen. But I proceeded to **Network Deactivate** the `W3TC plugin` anyway on each and every one of my networks.

Step 4 - After network deactivating the plugin, I proceeded to **Delete** it from the network admin panel on my primary site. When I did, I got this error on screen:

*W3 Total Cache Error: some files appear to be missing or out of place. Please re-install plugin or remove /home/abcdefg/public_html/wp-content/advanced-cache.php.W3 Total Cache Error: some files appear to be missing or out of place. Please re-install plugin or remove /home/abcdefg/public_html/wp-content/db.php.W3 Total Cache Error: some files appear to be missing or out of place. Please re-install plugin or remove /home/abcdefg/public_html/wp-content/object-cache.php.*

So I looked at the Drop-ins plugins as shown below:

[image]

Step 5 - next I FTP'd onto my server and *deleted these 3 files*:

`./wp-content/advanced-cache.php
./wp-content/db.php
./wp-content/object-cache.php`

Step 6 - I tried to *delete these 2 directories* via FTP and could not. So I telnet'd into server as root and deleted them:

`./wp-content/cache
./wp-content/w3tc-config`

Step 7 - I then removed this line of code from `wp-config.php`:

`define('WP_CACHE', true); // Added by W3 Total Cache`

Step 8 - I then removed these blocks of directives from `.htaccess`:

```
# 2015-02-05 updated as part of install of W3 Total Cache Plugin
# BEGIN W3TC Page Cache core
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} w3tc_preview [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_PREVIEW:_preview]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(comment_author|wp\-postpass|w3tc_logged_out|wordpress_logged_in|wptouch_switch_toggle) [NC]
    RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.html" -f
    RewriteRule .* "/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.html" [L]
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Page Cache core

# 2014-09-18 added as part of install of W3 Total Cache Plugin
# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    </IfModule>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/x-component application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon application/json
    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
        # DEFLATE by extension
        AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css htm html xml
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Browser Cache
```

Step 9 - refreshed the home page on the site numerous, numerous times. NO MORE FUNNY CHARACTERS !!!

Comment: Awesome @tammy! Glad you got it worked out - thanks for taking the time to share your process and solution. W3 Total Cache can do some pretty awesome things, but getting it and your server environment configured properly can take a lot of time, research, and head-scratching - thus why both the developer as well as third parties sometimes offer to configure the plugin for a premium! If you ever go back, I recommend starting small and building upwards - disable every W3TC feature and enable them one at a time, examining every configuration option and verifying stability each step of the way.